# importing numpy in Webots simulator run out environment variable

Tags: python, numpy, webots

I have try to import **numpy** in simulator **Webots(7.0.3)**, it's successful to be used until several times that **supervisor** revert the simulation. It comes out these error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyController.py", line 39, in <module>
    from numpy import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1103, in <module>
    os.environ.update(envbak)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 461, in update
    self[k] = dict[k]
   File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 422, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
ValueError: the environment variable is longer than 32767 bytes
```

The revert function is an original function for supervisor robot which can be called in Webots simulator:

```
supervisor.simulationRevert()
```

Can any body help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: it seems you are passing to much data via environment variables... why don't you use `pickle` or `json`?